# npm not functioning after installing python 3.5 and reinstalling both Git and npm on Windows

Tags: python, node.js, windows, git

I had node.js and npm working fine till I installed python 3.5 and probably missed up with my path (manually) .
git didnot recognise npm ; after I added "C:\Users\n17263" to my path npm was found by git.
But it does not install any package successfully.

Here is the Error screen after tying "npm install ws"

```
 bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\n17263\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


    C:\Users\n17263\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find "msbuild.exe". Do you have Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2008+ installed?
    gyp ERR! stack     at findMsbuild (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:122:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:104:11
    gyp ERR! stack     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:78:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:82:29)
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:93:16
    gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:83:15)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\n17263\node_modules\bufferutil
    gyp ERR! node -v v5.2.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1

    > utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\n17263\node_modules\utf-8-validate
    > node-gyp rebuild


    C:\Users\n17263\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find "msbuild.exe". Do you have Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2008+ installed?
    gyp ERR! stack     at findMsbuild (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:122:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:104:11
    gyp ERR! stack     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:78:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:82:29)
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:93:16
    gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:83:15)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\n17263\node_modules\utf-8-validate
    gyp ERR! node -v v5.2.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
    C:\Users\n17263
    └─┬ ws@0.8.1
      ├── options@0.0.6
      └── ultron@1.0.2

    npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\n17263\package.json'
    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON n17263 No description
    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON n17263 No repository field.
    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON n17263 No README data
    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON n17263 No license field.
```

Comment: my current path has "C:\Python27" and when trying "python --version" I get 
Python 2.7.9